# Visual Studio Integration Services becomes unresponsive

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, view, ssis, etl

I am developing ETL solutions in Visual Studio and as soon as I select a view from a SQL Server database, the Visual Studio freezes, and clicking anywhere results in the following notification: "Visual Studio is Busy".

It is very frustrating and I cannot finish creating my solution.

Any advice for making it faster and more responsive?

Comment: Try to use SSDT instead

Comment: @Amira whats the difference?  i thought VS2019 was better :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I. What happens when selecting a view as an OLE DB Source?

I created an SQL Server Profiler trace to track all T-SQL commands execute over the AdventureWorks2017 database while I am selecting the `[HumanResources].[vEmployee]` view as an OLE DB Source.

The following screenshot shows that the following command is executed twice:

```sql
set rowcount 1
select * from [HumanResources].[vEmployee]
```

[image]

This means that the OLE DB source limit the result set of the query to a single row and executes the `Select *` command over the selected view in order to extract the required metadata.

It is worth mentioning that the `SET ROWCOUNT 1` causes SQL Server to stop processing the query after the specified number of rows are returned. This means that only one row is requested and not all the view's data.

[image]

### II. Issue's possible reasons

The issue you mentioned mostly happens due to the following reasons:

#### (1) Third-party extensions installed in Visual Studio

In that case, you should try to start Visual Studio in safe mode to prevent loading third-party extensions. You can use the following command

```
devenv.exe /safemode
```

#### (2) View querying a large amount of data

Visual Studio may freeze if the view returns a huge amount of data or contains bad *JOINS*. You may solve this using a simple workaround. Alter the view's SQL and add a condition that only returns a few rows *(For example `SELECT TOP 1`)*. Then, use this view while designing the package. Once done, remove the added condition.

#### (3) Bad database design

Moreover, it is highly important that **your views are well designed and that the underlying tables have the appropriate indexes**. Besides, check that you don't have any issues related to the database design. For example:

##### (a) Index fragmentation

The index fragmentation is the index performance value in percentage, which can be fetched by SQL Server DMV. You can refer to the following article for more information:

- [How to identify and resolve SQL Server Index Fragmentation](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-identify-and-resolve-sql-server-index-fragmentation/)

##### (b) Large binary column

Make sure that the view does not include large binary columns since it highly affects the query execution.

- [Best Practices for tables with VARBINARY(MAX)](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/best-practices-for-tables-with-varbinarymax)
- [How Your SQL Server Data Type Choices Can Affect Database Performance](https://www.sentryone.com/white-papers/data-type-choice-affects-database-performance)

#### (4) Hardware issues

Even I do not think this should be the cause in that case. Try to check the available resources on your machine. For Example:

##### (a) Drive out of storage

If using windows, check the `C:` drive storage *(default system databases directory)* and the drive where the databases are stored and make sure they are not full.

##### (b) Server is out of memory

Make sure that your machine is not running out of memory. You can simply use the Task Manager to identify the amount of available memory.

#### (5) Optimizing Visual Studio performance

The last thing to mention is that there are several recommendations to improve the performance of Visual Studio. Feel free to check them:

- [Optimize Visual Studio performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/optimize-visual-studio-performance?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 1):

This can sometimes happen when you try to validate a select statement against a huge table. Depending on the RDBMS , some data sources while doing the validation do not do a good job of returning just metadata to validate against, and instead run `Select * from table`. So, validation can take what seems like forever.

Try to check if this is actually happening , check the running queries on the RDBMS in the package, when you load up the package.

Otherwise try copying the package and switch to the XML and rebuild it until you find issue.  Remove the problem from your XML file, save, and redraw in the designer.